# java.awt.graphics.* draw oval function is not working

Tags: java, graphics, awt

I need to draw a circle in  project I'm working on, I am using `java.awt.graphics.*` to draw it using the `drawOval();` method, but it is not working.

Here is a code snippet:

```
public void paint(Graphics g)
{
    g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    g.drawOval(480,480,200,200);
    g.fillOval(480, 480, 200, 200);
}
```

Comment: Whats not working?

Comment: *"Here is a code snippet:"* For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [mre].

Comment: Add a line `@Override` before the method. How do you show it. A JFrame with a custom JPanel child with your method? Then that panel would by default use a BorderLayout and resize to fill the frame.

Comment: The `fillOval` method works.  You don't have to draw the oval first.  Oracle has a helpful tutorial, [Creating a GUI With Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).  Skip the Learning Swing with the NetBeans IDE section.  The [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) lesson will show you how to draw on a drawing `JPanel`.

Comment: “it is not working”—How can you tell?